# How to append a generated table from a different wsheet to another generated table by filtering through a conditional in Power Query?

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I created a power query, where my source data is from division A (wsheet 1) of the company accounts wbook, applied my PQ steps, and generated a table. I will then split that generated table based on 3 departments into 3 different wsheets (using basic excel table filter by dept, cut and paste into other wsheets).

However, I want to replicate the same query for another wsheet division B (almost same columns with a few new columns added) from the same source workbook, and generate a report table.

Once the report table is generated, I would like to add that table where it is filtered by department 1 (both divisions share one common department) and add that data to the generated report for department 1 of Division A. The report workbook will essentially have 3 PQ generated tables - a wsheet report for Division A Dept2, a wsheet report for Division A Dept 3, and a wsheet report for Division A and B WHERE it is only DEPT1.

How would I achieve this so the wsheet report always moves the DEPT1 Division B accounts to the wsheet report of Division A and B WHERE it is only DEPT1 every time I refresh the report wbook, when new entries are added each day from the source wbook?

Comment: So what have you done to attempt to achieve this? This site can assist you if you share your code/script but we are not a coding service; we assist you with the issues you have and cannot handle stuff like this from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Each time a PQ runs, it does a full refresh from the source data, and completely empties and reloads the target table.

So to achieve what you want, you just need multiple Queries, each with the relevant filters, and refresh them each day.

To avoid duplicating Query steps, you can base a new Query on the output of an existing Query using the **Reference** feature.